# Puma phased-restart not change state to new release folder?

Tags: capistrano, puma, ruby-on-rails-7

**Puma config**

Puma: 6.4.0

```
#!/usr/bin/env puma

directory "/home/prj/current"
rackup "/home/prj/current/config.ru"

environment "staging"
pidfile "/home/prj/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid"

state_path "/home/prj/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state"
stdout_redirect '/home/prj/shared/log/puma_access.log', '/home/prj/shared/log/puma_error.log', true

bind 'unix:///home/prj/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock'

workers 2
max_threads_count = 16
min_threads_count = 1
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count

prune_bundler

on_worker_boot do
  require "active_record"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect! rescue ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end

before_fork do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect! if defined?(ActiveRecord)
end
```

**SystemdReload Command**

```
WorkingDirectory=/home/prj/current

ExecReload=/bin/bash -l -c 'bundle exec pumactl -S /home/prj/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state -F /home/prj/shared/config/puma.rb phased-restart'
```

**Capistrano Config**

```
set :puma_phased_restart, true
set :puma_enable_socket_service, true
set :puma_systemctl_user, :system
```

After deploy capistrano run

```
/bin/systemctl reload puma
```

When I show state of puma, working directory is previous release although cluster reload to the new one. So How can I know newest code already running or not? Why puma state not change directory working?

```
cat /home/prj/current/tmp/pids/puma.state 
---
pid: 4475
running_from: "/home/prj/releases/20231206070847"

ps aux | grep puma
deploy      4475  0.0  1.1 105820 11392 ?        Ss   Dec06   0:05 puma 6.4.0 (unix:///home/prj/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock) [20231206070847]
deploy     22985  0.1 16.6 785688 162364 ?       Sl   12:42   0:04 puma: cluster worker 0: 4475 [20231206070847]
deploy     23001  0.1 22.7 812040 221384 ?       Sl   12:42   0:04 puma: cluster worker 1: 4475 [20231206070847]

ls /home/prj/releases/
20231206073136  20231206073247  20231207032212
```